# How to color HTML elements based on parsing a user command string

Tags: javascript, parsing, xampp

I'm working on a little parsing thing to color objects.
For an example, you could type red:Hi!: and "Hi!" would be red.

This is my not working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function post()
{
    var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
    var submit = document.getElementById("post");
    var text = submit.value;
    <?php str_replace("red:*:",'<i class="red">*</i>',text); ?>
    preview.value = text;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't use PHP to change your page on the client side, you will need to use Javascript for this.

Comment: The PHP is not changing the page, the PHP is setting the value that JavaScript uses.

Comment: But you see it's trying to set the value that javascript uses at the time javascript is executed AND by using a javascript variable. The PHP isn't running inside their browser. It's just going to print one thing at page load, that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two massive problems here.

1. You can't str_replace with wildcards like you are (the asterisks you use are just that - the asterisk character, not a placeholder).
2. Your idea of the page-rendering process is off - you can't just call some PHP code in JavaScript and have it update the page. Any PHP code will be executed and printed when your page is generated on the server - it can't interact with the page like JavaScript can (JS can because it is executed within the browser, but the browser never actually sees your PHP code as you can check by going to View->Source and seeing what you see). You certainly cannot reference a JavaScript variable from PHP.

Two options.

#### Option 1 - Proper Server-Side

if you want to colour objects on page load based on post, do something like this:

```
<?php 
  # If the value was posted
  $raw = isset($_POST['userstring']) ? $_POST['userstring'] : "";
  # Split it based on ':'
  $parsed = explode(':', $raw);

  $colorClass = "";
  $text = "";

  if (count($parsed) >= 2)
  {
    $colorClass = $parsed[0];
    $text = $parsed[1];
  }

?>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="userstring" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="preview">
<?php if (strlen($text) > 0) { ?>
  <i class="<?php echo $colorClass; ?>">
    <?php echo $text; ?>
  </i>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

#### Option 2 - Proper Client-Side

Include jQuery in your <head> tag to make your life easier. If you really don't want to include jQuery you can still change the jQuery calls to your getElementById etc. (you'll want to replace the html() call with '.innerhtml' I think - just look it up).

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">                           
  function post() {                 
    var split = $('#userinput).val().split(separator, limit)        
    if (split.length >= 2) {     
      var color = split[0];              
      var text = split[1]; 
      $('#preview').html('<i class="' + color + '">' + text + '</i>');    
    }
    return false; // Stop form submit
  }                           
</script> 

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="post()">
  <input id="userinput" type="text" name="userstring" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="preview">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing server and client side technologies here. The code in the php lock is evaluated once (while still on the server). You're looking for something that will operate entirely on the client side.

This means you need to look into Javascript regular expressions, instead of PHP preg_match type stuff.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

You're looking for this type of thing:

stringObject.replace( regularExpressionVarOrLiteral, replacement );

Josh